# mount a sd-card image - change files on a partition and write back

Tags: linux, bash, disk, loopback

i want to mount an IMG file (which >1 partitions on it), change some files at one (ext4) partition and write the result back to this img.

One way would be to write the img to a sd card, change there and make an image again. But i dont have a SDcard writer(!) and i think this way is abit complex anyway. Anyway, I tried this once a different computer, it works this way but its very complex and time consuming. Trying with a "loopback device" didnt worked for me.

Can someone tell me how to do this on an Ubuntu (for example with a loopback device?).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and to add a tag for the programming language you're using.  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: This really has nothing to do with programming, and so should probably be moved to a different board, but I would suggest you start by researching `kpartx` and `losetup`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create loopback device with:

```
losetup  -P /dev/loop0 file
```

then it will show all partitions on that file in the form of:

```
/dev/loop0
/dev/loop0p1
/dev/loop0p2
```

here is a quote from the man losetup

> -P, --partscan
>                 Force the kernel to scan the partition table on a newly created loop device.